@typescript-eslint/no-confusing-void-expression Error with TypeScript Function Returning undefined
I am encountering a linting error in my TypeScript code related to the @typescript-eslint/no-confusing-void-expression rule. My function, getNestedProperty, is designed to return either a value or undefined. Despite the function itself being correct, the linting error is triggered in certain test cases, where undefined is being tested.
Here's the function that is causing the issue:
type NestedProperty<T, P extends string> = P extends `${infer K}.${infer Rest}`
    ? K extends keyof T
        ? NestedProperty<T[K], Rest>
        : K extends `${number}`
        ? T extends Array<infer U>
            ? NestedProperty<U, Rest>
            : never
        : never
    : P extends keyof T
    ? T[P]
    : never;


export const getNestedProperty = <T, P extends string>(
    obj: T,
    path: P
): NestedProperty<T, P> | undefined => {
    const keys = path.split('.') as Array<string | number>;

    return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
        if (acc === undefined || acc === null) {
            return undefined;
        }

        if (Array.isArray(acc)) {
            const index = typeof key === 'string' ? Number(key) : key;
            if (Number.isInteger(index) && index >= 0 && index < acc.length) {
                return acc[index];
            }
            return undefined;
        } else if (typeof acc === 'object') {
            return (acc as Record<string | number, unknown>)[key];
        }

        return undefined;
    }, obj) as NestedProperty<T, P> | undefined;
};

When running tests, I get the following linting error:
Placing a void expression inside another expression is forbidden. Move it to its own statement instead  @typescript-eslint/no-confusing-void-expression

Here's an example of a test case that triggers this lint error:
it('should return the correct value for a root level array by index', () => {
    const obj = [42, 43];
    const result = getNestedProperty(obj, '1');
    expect(result).toBe(43);
});

I have ensured that getNestedProperty correctly returns undefined where expected. I have checked the TypeScript and ESLint configurations but haven't found any issues.
How can I fix the linting error @typescript-eslint/no-confusing-void-expression related to this getNestedProperty function? Do I need to modify the function itself, or is there a way to adjust the test cases or linting rules to resolve this?
Test cases are successful.

Well, while that code is definitely confusing and linters are useful, you shouldn't be a slave to your linter if and when you know better. That said, your type assertion at the buttom is worrying.
